# Datepicker default to this Sunday

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to customize this script so that so that `onclick` `#startdatepicker` would show this Sunday's date in `yy-mm-dd` format and `#enddatepicker` would show next sat. date by default.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#startdatepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
        $("#enddatepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
Start Date: <input type="text" id="startdatepicker"/><br />
End Date: <input type="text" id="enddatepicker"/><br />`
```

Comment: I assume you want to do that without giving your inputs initial values that correspond to those dates?

Comment: Correct I want it to automatically display next Sunday's date by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want the datePicker to default to the next Sunday (regardless of today's date), try:

```
$(function() {
    var sunday = new Date(),               // new Date object for current day
        dow = sunday.getDay(),             // day of week (0-6)
        toAdd = dow === 0 ? 0 : 7 - dow;   // days to move forward

    $( "#startpicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: toAdd
    });

    $( '#endpicker' ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: toAdd+6
    });
});​
```

The same can be done to find the following Saturday, just add 6 more days.

http://jsfiddle.net/dYEMn/3

Comment: Sure; see this udpated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dYEMn/5/ In this case, you don't need to set a `defaultDate` if the text field is already populated with your desired default date string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [defaultDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) option to specify the date that the datepicker shows when it's opened and the `<input>`'s value is blank. All you'd need to do is obtain Date objects or Strings that represent the dates in question, and pass those when initialising the datepickers on the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values with the picker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#startdatepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            defaultDate: '12-08-05',
        });
        $("#enddatepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            defaultDate: '12-08-12',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

MDN has nice documentation about [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you can use [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to find out how many days you need to go forward to get to this sunday and next saturday.

http://jsfiddle.net/VesQ/ZdmCE/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get current date
    var now = new Date();
    // Get the day, 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday
    var day = now.getDay();

    // How many days to this sunday
    var daysToSunday;
    if (day == 0) {
        // Sunday is now
        daysToSunday = 0;
    } else {
        daysToSunday = 7 - day;
    }

    // Days to next saturday is simple:
    var daysToNextSaturday = daysToSunday + 6;

    // See defaultDate option,
    // http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate
    $("#startdatepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: daysToSunday
    });
    $("#enddatepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: daysToNextSaturday
    });
});
```